# MATLAB - generate confusion matrix from classifier

Tags: matlab, classification, roc

I have some test data and labels:

```
testZ = [0.25, 0.29, 0.62, 0.27, 0.82, 1.18, 0.93, 0.54, 0.78, 0.31, 1.11, 1.08, 1.02];

testY = [1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2];
```

I then sort them:

```
[sZ, ind] = sort(testZ); %%Sorts Z, and gets indexes of Z
sY = testY(ind); %%Sorts Y by index
[N, n] = size(testZ');
```

This will then give the sorted Y data. At each element of the sorted Y data, I want to classify each point to the left as being of type 1 and everything to the right being class 2; This will then be repeated for every point of the data. How can I do this and find out for each element the variables:

- TP(true positive) - the elements correctly marked as 1
- FP(false positive) - the elements incorrectly marked as 1
- TN(true negative) - the elements correctly marked as 2
- FN(false negatives) - the elements incorrectly marked as 2

The purpose of this is so that I can create an ROC curve for the classifier as part of some school work.

Comment: When you say : 'each point to the left', how many points does that represent? The same amount of points than 1s in `testY`?

Comment: @BillBokeey The first point should have no elements on the left and 13 (the amount of elements in sY) to the right, then the confusion matrix is found, then the same process is repeated for the rest of the points

Comment: Okay, i'm posting an answer

Comment: Will you have very big datasets?

Comment: @BillBokeey no the datasets should be about the same size as the test data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code for plotting ROC and finding AUC value:

```
tot_op = testZ;
targets = testY;
th_vals= sort(tot_op);

for i = 1:length(th_vals)
  b_pred = (tot_op>=th_vals(i,1));
  TP = sum(b_pred == 1 & targets == 2);
  FP = sum(b_pred == 1 & targets == 1);
  TN = sum(b_pred == 0 & targets == 1);
  FN = sum(b_pred == 0 & targets == 2);
  sens(i) = TP/(TP+FN);
  spec(i) = TN/(TN+FP);
end


figure(2);
cspec = 1-spec;
cspec = cspec(end:-1:1);
sens = sens(end:-1:1);
plot(cspec,sens,'k');

AUC = sum(0.5*(sens(2:end)+sens(1:end-1)).*(cspec(2:end) - cspec(1:end-1)));
fprintf('\nAUC: %g \n',AUC);
```

Above code is the modified version given on http://www.dcs.gla.ac.uk/~srogers/firstcourseml/matlab/chapter5/svmroc.html

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the points and then use logical indexing and element-wise Boolean operators to get most of what you want.

```
 for i = 1:length(sY)
      classification = [ones(1,i-1) 2*ones(1,length(sy)-i+1)];
      isTruePositive = ( (sY == classification) & (sY == 1) );
      numberOfTruePositive = sum(isTruePositive);
      % Similar for other cases.

      % Use the result in the loop or store it somewhere - as written here
      % variables are over-written each iteration in the loop.
 end
```

I didn't run this, so you might need some tweaks, but this should get you most of the way.

Comment: I believe you made a mistake at `2*ones(i,length(sy))`. Wouldn't it be `2*ones(1,length(sy)-i+1)`? Plus `numberOfTruePositive` would be overriden on each iteration and you should use `ii` instead of `i` to index your loop

Comment: @BillBokeey Thanks.  I fixed the length with an edit.  You're right that the variables in the example will be over-written.  Since we don't know what the OP wants to do with the result, I didn't try to solve that problem for him.  Obviously it needs to be stored somewhere persistent or used somewhere in the loop before the next iteration.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, I will test this out tomorrow and see if I can make it fit my needs and keep you posted!