# Plotting Roc Curve in SVM

Tags: r, machine-learning, svm, roc

I am trying to create a ROC curve for an SVM and here is the code I have used :

```
#learning from training
#tuned <- tune.svm(y~., data=train, gamma = 10^(-6:-1), cost = 10^(1:2))
summary(tuned)


svmmodel<-svm(y~., data=train, method="C-classification",
              kernel="radial", gamma = 0.01, cost = 100,cross=5, probability=TRUE) 

svmmodel

#predicting the test data
svmmodel.predict<-predict(svmmodel,subset(test,select=-y),decision.values=TRUE)
svmmodel.probs<-attr(svmmodel.predict,"decision.values")
svmmodel.class<-predict(svmmodel,test,type="class")
svmmodel.labels<-test$y
#analyzing result
svmmodel.confusion<-confusion.matrix(svmmodel.labels,svmmodel.class)
svmmodel.accuracy<-prop.correct(svmmodel.confusion)

#roc analysis for test data
svmmodel.prediction<-prediction(svmmodel.probs,svmmodel.labels)
svmmodel.performance<-performance(svmmodel.prediction,"tpr","fpr")
svmmodel.auc<-performance(svmmodel.prediction,"auc")@y.values[[1]]
```

but the problem that the curve ROC is somthing like this :

[image]

Comment: This is very data-specific and no-one can say much without seeing what's in tuned. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

I have answered similar question at [MATLAB - generate confusion matrix from classifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33523931/matlab-generate-confusion-matrix-from-classifier/33542453#33542453)
By using the code given at the link above, If you get inverse ROC curve like you have shown in your figure then replace the following lines (in the code given at the link):
1. Replace the line in the code given on the link.

```
b_pred = (tot_op>=th_vals(i,1));
```

by

```
b_pred = (tot_op<=th_vals(i,1));
```

2. Replace the line

```
AUC = sum(0.5*(sens(2:end)+sens(1:end-1)).*(cspec(2:end) - cspec(1:end-1)));
```

by

```
AUC = sum(0.5*(sens(2:end)+sens(1:end-1)).*(cspec(1:end-1) - cspec(2:end)));
```

in the code given on the link.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done very easily with '[ROCR](https://rocr.bioinf.mpi-sb.mpg.de/)' package.
I use something like this to get the ROC curve.

```
p1<- predict(svm,test, type="decision")
pr<-prediction(p1, test$status)
prf<- performance(pr, measure="tpr",x.measure="fpr")
plot(prf)
lines(x = c(0,1), y = c(0,1),col="blue")
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you solve the problem?
I had same problem with you, the reverse ROC and AUC were obtained from the testset.

In my case, It can be solved to sort the training dataset.

For example,

```
train <- train[order(train$y, decreasing = TRUE),]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using decision.values, try this:

```
fit = f(x,y,probability = TRUE)
pred = prediction(attr(predict(fit,x_test, probability = TRUE), "probabilities")[,2], test[,colnames(test) == y_name])
```